# Start menu width in WIN 10 cannot be adjusted

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

Windows 10 Home, Version 21H1

When the TaskBar is on the left side of the screen (always my choice), after open "Start", I cannot adjust the width by mouse dragging. This is not normal. I can though adjust the hight.

I did recently clean upgraded windows...

Any hints for a fix?

Noah H.

Comment: The Windows taskbar always had the option to fixate it so it can't be resized. Do you have activated this option?

Comment: That option freezes the resizing of the TaskBar only. The "Start area" normally can always be resized. In my case (Taskbar on the left side of the scree) I can adjust the height by dragging, but not the width. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Seemingly, the ability to change the width depends on the Display setting "Text Size".
It works fine if Text Size is 150% or below. Mine is usually set at 175% (poor eye sight).
Yet, I always used that setting, and in the past I had no restrictions.

Anyhow, I can live with that...